# Logout from every computer I've logged in

Tags: support, logout

I know how to log out of Stack Overflow, but what I don't know is how can I log out from every computer/mobile phone I have logged in in the past.

Is there a way for that? I searched and found in one post that I need to flag one of my posts so that I get attention from moderators, and I need to tell them and they will help me.

I don't know if this is a fast process, but what happens if someone missuses my account in that time?

My question: is there a simple and faster way to log out from Stack Overflow in every single device I have logged in in the past?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the normal log out screen - it has a checkbox for logging you out everywhere:

[image: Log out on all devices]

Note that you may want to also log out of your OpenID provider as well - though how that works for all your devices depends on your OpenID provider.